# can we parse array element and a value from a android xml array

Tags: android, android-xml

Can we parse a array element and a value from a android array use in xml layouts.

```
<string-array name="country_arrays">

    <item>ABC</item>
    <item>DEF</item>
    <item>FHI</item>
    <item>JKL</item>

</string-array>
```

in this array we can parse only String values but I want to parse a id too attached to each strings.
In HTML we can parse a value attribute with a HTML element. I don't know whether this can be done with Android but if it is possible it will reduce lot of work, please help me to correct this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it is impossible, but you can use id when you load array into you java code.